# How to compile against a custom kernel (Debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, compiling, kernel-modules, header-file

There is a file `version.h` in `/usr/include/linux`. Many header files include this file and use the `defines` in there for their own `ifdefs`.

However, when I compile my own kernel, I cannot see how this can possibly be reflected correctly in e.g.  `version.h`.

Actually this holds for all kernel-related header files. AFAICS `/usr/include/linux` always represent the kernel which came with my distribution and neither the running kernel, nor the kernel I tell `make` by means of `SYSSRC`.

In the past I resorted to creating symlinks to my own kernel sources, but I have a feeling that this is not the correct way.

How is this supposed to work? How do I compile (e.g. a kernel module) against a custom kernel?

Comment: I imagine that the package-manager that installs your system, sorts it out. Also if there is a change (not just an addition), then every single program would need recompiling. So I do not imagine that these things change much.

Comment: My actual problem is with a kernel module. There I could understand that you really need the correct headers. For userspace programs you are probably right, though I don't quite know why they would need kernel headers at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When configuring a system against your own custom kernel, I would suggest adding a name to the current version in your modified kernel sources.

For instance, in Armbian they create their own kernel packages, and add a -sunxi to kernel.release.

Takin as an example modifying the 4.6.3 kernel version:

```
root@ruir:/usr/src/linux-headers-4.6.3-sunxi# grep -ri 4.6.3-sunxi *
include/generated/utsrelease.h:#define UTS_RELEASE "4.6.3-sunxi"
include/config/kernel.release:4.6.3-sunxi
```

and also, for the kernel modules, in `/lib/modules/4.6.3-sunxi/build`:

```
include/generated/utsrelease.h:#define UTS_RELEASE "4.6.3-sunxi"
include/config/auto.conf.cmd:ifneq "$(KERNELVERSION)" "4.6.3-sunxi"
include/config/kernel.release:4.6.3-sunxi
```

(see [installing sysdig in ARM / Armbian Jessie - module compiled in wrong kernel version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273983/installing-sysdig-in-arm-armbian-jessie-module-compiled-in-wrong-kernel-vers) )

As we can see, this can be seen in `uname -r`:

```
$uname -r
4.6.3-sunxi
```

As for the custom kernel packages:

```
$dpkg -l | grep sunxi
ii  linux-dtb-next-sunxi             5.16                                  armhf        Linux DTB, version 4.6.3-sunxi
ii  linux-firmware-image-next-sunxi  5.16                                  armhf        Linux kernel firmware, version 4.6.3-sunxi
ii  linux-headers-next-sunxi         5.16                                  armhf        Linux kernel headers for 4.6.3-sunxi on armhf
ii  linux-image-next-sunxi           5.16                                  armhf        Linux kernel, version 4.6.3-sunxi
```

As for adding your own headers of your compile kernel, I will refer to [KernelHeaders](https://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders) (emphasis as bold is mine); if you are replacing minor kernel versions you may (or may not) get away with only `make headers_install`.

> User space programs
>
> In general, user space programs are built against the header files
>   provided by the distribution, typically from a package named
>   glibc-devel, glibc-kernheaders or linux-libc-dev. These header files
>   are often from an older kernel version, and they cannot safely be
>   replaced without rebuilding glibc as well. In particular, installing
>   /usr/include/linux as a symbolic link to /usr/src/linux/include or
>   /lib/modules/*/build/include/linux is highly discouraged as it
>   frequently breaks rebuilding applications. For instance, older kernels
>   had the architecture specific header files in include/asm-${arch}
>   instead of arch/${arch}/include/asm and had on a symlink to the
>   architecture specific directory.
>
> **The correct way to package the header files for a distribution is to
>   run 'make headers_install' from the kernel source directory to install
>   the headers into /usr/include and then rebuild the C library package,
>   with a dependency on the specific version of the just installed kernel
>   headers.**
>
> If you are distributing a user space program that depends on a
>   specific version of some kernel headers, e.g. because your program
>   runs only on patched or very recent kernels, you cannot rely on the
>   headers in /usr/include. You also cannot use the header files from
>   /usr/src/linux/include or /lib/modules/*/build/include/ because they
>   have not been prepared for inclusion in user space. The kernel should
>   warn you about this if you try it and point you to this Wiki page. The
>   correct way to address this problem is to isolate the specific
>   interfaces that you need, e.g. a single header file that is patched in
>   a new kernel providing the ioctl numbers for a character device used
>   by your program. In your own program, add a copy of that source file,
>   with a notice that it should be kept in sync with new kernel versions.
>   If your program is not licensed under GPLv2, make sure you have
>   permission from the author of that file to distribute it under the
>   license of your own program. Since your program now depends on kernel
>   interfaces that may not be present in a regular kernel, it's a good
>   idea to add run-time checks that make sure the kernel understands the
>   interface and give a helpful error message if there is no fallback to
>   an older interface.

Also for kernel development; or compiling a kernel/module for a different server or for a different kernel with multiple kernel versions installed, SYSSRC maybe be used to specify an alternate kernel source location.

Comment: I did add my custom suffix. I don't have a problem with /usr/src/linux-headers-xxx or the modules. My problem is with /usr/include/linux. This directory exists only once and if a program does #include <linux/version.h> it'll include from there, doesn't it? So it will always get the same kernel-headers, i.e. the ones which came with my distribution and not the ones from my custom kernel.

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: Good. One last question: what is the point of the SYSSRC variable? What could a kernel module possibly want from the kernel sources particularly if the headers are taken from /usr/include.

Comment: Added again to the answer.

Comment: I know what SYSSRC does, but I don't know why it is necessary. The headers are still taken from /usr/include (AFAICS). So something else of interest must be in the kernel source tree, but what?

Comment: low level kernel structures, and more differences across versions. for compiling modules and binaries that interact deeply with the kernel with an active version for a different version. say compiling a custom kernel module or even something like dtrace or sysdig